# Avoid overwriting of files with "for" loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes (df_cleaned) created from multiple csv files chosen by the user.

My objective is to save each dataframe within the df_cleaned list as a separate csv file locally.

I have the following code done which saves the file with its original title. But I see that it overwrites and manages to save a copy of *only* the last dataframe.

How can I fix it? According to my very basic knowledge perhaps I could use a break-continue statement in the loop? But I do not know how to implement it correctly.

```
for i in range(len(df_cleaned)):
    outputFile = df_cleaned[i].to_csv(r'C:\...\Data Docs\TrainData\{}.csv'.format(name))
print('Saving of files as csv is complete.')
```

Comment: Where is the variable `name` modified? It seems to me that it overwrites because you write in the same file (ie saving data into the same filename) within the loop.

Comment: @Ary that might be the issue. Do you know how I can fix this? I do have a list with the file names as a separate part of the code, if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way of solving. Just figured out the answer myself. Posting to help someone else.

> fileNames is a list I created at the start of the code to save the
>   names of the files chosen by the user.

```
for i in range(len(df_cleaned)):
    outputFile = df_cleaned[i].to_csv(r'C:\...\TrainData\{}.csv'.format(fileNames[i]))
print('Saving of files as csv is complete.')
```

Saves a separate copy for each file in the defined directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different name for each file, as an example in the following I attach the index to `name`:

```
for i in range(len(df_cleaned)):
    outputFile = df_cleaned[i].to_csv(r'C:\...\Data Docs\TrainData\{0}_{1}.csv'.format(name,i))
print('Saving of files as csv is complete.')
```

this will create a list of files named `<name>_N.csv` with N = 0, ..., len(df_cleaned)-1.

Comment: Gives me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\...\\Data Docs\\TrainData\\fileLast.xlsm_0.csv'` where fileLast is the name of the last file in the list. I do have a list with the file names as a separate part of the code, if that helps?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the windows-like signal, but the "..." in the file name looks suspicious.

As for the file names you can easily use them, e.g. `name = nameList[i]` in the same loop, assuming the list of the file names is `nameList`

Comment: First try of your code gave me the error above. Just found a solution to it myself though, will post it shortly. Thanks a lot for the effort :)